# How to use Inception Network for Regression

Tags: image, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to input an image and get a continuous number as an output.

I built a NN which takes an image with only a single node in the Hidden layer with a linear activation function. However, the model predicts the same number for the given input.

Hence I would like to use the Inception Network for this problem. Based on a recent paper by Google.

Link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06435.pdf

x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score -1):

This is absolutely possible! The [example](https://keras.io/applications/#fine-tune-inceptionv3-on-a-new-set-of-classes) from keras documentation on pre-trained models should help you with your endeavor. Make sure to adjust the output layer and the loss of your new model.

**Edit:** code example for your specific case

```py
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import backend as K

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# and a linear output layer
prediction = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers to non trainable)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error')

# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
model.fit_generator(...)
```

This is just training the new top layers, if you like to fine-tune the lower layers as well have a look at the [example](https://keras.io/applications/#fine-tune-inceptionv3-on-a-new-set-of-classes) from the documentation.